# Advance Installer Configuring database from command line

Tags: command-line, advanced-installer

Hello all I am able to do the following operations from command line

```
1.Create new AIP project 
2.Edit the project by adding folder and required services
```

is it possible to achieve the same for database so that it should work similar to AddFolder so that there is no need to open the dialog and do it manually

Comment: http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/command-line-editing.html has a bunch of command groupings below it, however I don't see anything related to DBs; if you can fetch the db connection string from the registry you could set that as a command.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to modify the [SQL Databases](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/sql-databases.html) section of your AIP project, then they do not have command line support for this. Maybe you can post on their [forum](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewforum.php?f=1) a feature request for such command option.